# How can I also display text when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I also display text when these custom "buttons" are clicked? I would imagine it was an if statement but i'm unsure on how to incorporate
that and all the other statements needed to do so, I've tried doing so but have had no success and was wondering if anyone could help?

```js
function alter() {
  var button = document.getElementById('addButton');
  button.setAttribute('class', 'cancelButton');
}

function alter2() {
  var button = document.getElementById('leftButton');
  button.setAttribute('class', 'cancelLeftButton');
}

function alter3() {
  var button = document.getElementById('rightButton');
  button.setAttribute('class', 'cancelRightButton');
}
```

```css
#addButton {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
}
.cancelButton {
  animation: turnToCross 1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.000, 1.650, 1.000, 1.650);
}
@keyframes turnToCross {
  to {
    border-radius: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: #AD80FF;
  }
  from {}
}
#leftButton {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  margin: -50px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
}
.cancelLeftButton {
  animation: turnToCross 1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.000, 1.650, 1.000, 1.650);
}
@keyframes turnToCross {
  to {
    border-radius: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: #AD80FF;
  }
  from {}
}
#rightButton {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 25%;
  margin: -50px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
}
.cancelRightButton {
  animation: turnToCross 1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.000, 1.650, 1.000, 1.650);
}
@keyframes turnToCross {
  to {
    border-radius: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: #AD80FF;
  }
  from {}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div onclick="alter()" id="addButton">+</div>
  <div onclick="alter2()" id="leftButton">+</div>
  <div onclick="alter3()" id="rightButton">+</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where in this code is the attempt to show texts when the buttons are clicked?

Comment: do you want to add custom text in div when clicked?

Comment: add in each click function button.innerHTML = "place your text";

Comment: I removed my attempt as I didn't want to confuse anything..... and when the button is clicked I would like it to do the animation and display my own custom text yeah.....

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to add an element you want your text to be shown

```
  <body>
        <div onclick="alter()" id="addButton">+</div>
        <div onclick="alter2()" id="leftButton">+</div>
        <div onclick="alter3()" id="rightButton">+</div>
        <div id="showhereid "></div>
    </body>
```

Then, inside of the function of button to be clicked, you're gonna insert this line of code

```
 document.getElementById('showhereid').innerHTML = "your text";
```

Your javascript code will look like this:

```
<script>
            function alter() {
                var button = document.getElementById('addButton');
                button.setAttribute('class', 'cancelButton');
                document.getElementById('showhereid').innerHTML = "your text";
            }

            function alter2() {
                var button = document.getElementById('leftButton');
                button.setAttribute('class', 'cancelLeftButton');
               document.getElementById('showhereid').innerHTML = "your text";
            }

            function alter3() {
                var button = document.getElementById('rightButton');
                button.setAttribute('class', 'cancelRightButton');
                document.getElementById('showhereid').innerHTML = "your text";
            }
        </script>
```

See if helps :)

Comment: Yeah this works thank you! I thought I had to add an if statement but obviously that click function is already there and i'm just adding in the code! Thank you so much!

Comment: Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/8drmes17/) of this answer.

Comment: about the jsfiddle: there is an extra space on div id. But other than that it's working fine. My bad :) But I think you figure out just fine.

Comment: how would I get it to display an image instead of text?

Comment: you just put the HTML code for image instead of text. Like this:  document.getElementById('showhereid').innerHTML = '<img src ="image_path.jpg">'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming @Farhan is correct, you can do this:

```
button.innerHTML = "Text";
```

Example from your code:

```
function alter() {
    var button = document.getElementById('addButton');
    button.setAttribute('class', 'cancelButton');
    button.innerHTML = "My text";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, add `button.innerHTML = "place your text";` in each click function

```
<script>
    function alter() {
        var button = document.getElementById('addButton');
        button.setAttribute('class', 'cancelButton');
        button.innerHTML = "place your text";
    }

    function alter2() {
        var button = document.getElementById('leftButton');
        button.setAttribute('class', 'cancelLeftButton');
        button.innerHTML = "place your text";
    }

    function alter3() {
        var button = document.getElementById('rightButton');
        button.setAttribute('class', 'cancelRightButton');
        button.innerHTML = "place your text";
    }
</script>
```